# Rails - Capture form data from a non-rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, redactor

Am using [redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/s3/) WYSIWYG. From the Docs, it supports Amazon S3 image upload. I had made a separate simple rails app that uploads images to amazon.

The HTML

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => {:multipart => true, :accept => "image/gif,image/png,image/jpg"} do |f| %>

   <div>
     <label>Image</label>
   </div>
   <div style="width: 400px;" >
     <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile'  %>
   </div>

   <div>
      <%= f.submit "Upload image", :class => "button" %>
   </div>

<% end  %>
```

I have a create action in my ImagesController

Create action (using aws-gem)

```
def create
  fileUp = params[:upload]
  orig_filename =  fileUp['datafile'].original_filename
  filename = sanitize_filename(orig_filename)
  AWS::S3::S3Object.store(filename, fileUp['datafile'].read, @@BUCKET, :access => :public_read)
  url = AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(filename, @@BUCKET, :authenticated => false)
  @image = Image.new(params[:image])
  @image.filename = filename
  @image.url = url;
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Image saved! "
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render '/images/new'
  end
end
```

Am trying to apply the same logic to upload images in redactor. I have this in my javascript

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $('#answer_content').redactor({
            imageUpload: '<%= upload_path %>'
        });
    }
);
```

In my routes.rb

```
  match "upload" => "answers#imageUpload"
```

I am not sure how to pass redactor form data to my server side script. Inspecting the html for the upload script in redactor

[image]

```
<input type="file" id="redactor_file" name="file">
```

How do I capture this data in my rails method just like in my other method? Am not sure what params are passed by this redactor HTML. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?